# Transfer a value from a function to another function

Tags: javascript

I'm currently having hard time trying to figure out how I can transfer a value from a function to another function in my javascript. As you can see here, I functions running. I want to know how I can transfer the result from the `get_short_url` function to the `openTwitter` function.

Basically the `short_url` inside the `console.log` holds the value that I needed to be transferred to the `openTwitter` function

```
var login = "username";
var api_key = "api_key";
var long_url = "http://www.kozlenko.info";

function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function(response)
        {
            func(response.data.url);
        }
    );
}

get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function(short_url) {
    console.log(short_url)
});
```

---

```
function openTwitter(url) {
  var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text= PLACE short_url value here,
  win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

$('#twitter').on('click', function() {
    openTwitter();
});
```

Comment: Same way you're doing it now; in `openTwitter` you'd pass a callback to `get_short_url`. Please use consistent naming conventions, though.

Comment: so basically it is `function openTwitter(url, short_url)`? Sorry for my ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Call `openTwitter` from inside the callback of `get_short_url`.

```
var login = "username";
var api_key = "api_key";
var long_url = "http://www.kozlenko.info";

function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func) {
    $.getJSON(
        "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": long_url
        },
        function(response)
        {
            func(response.data.url);
        }
    );
}

function openTwitter(short_url) {
  var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + short_url,
  win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

$('#twitter').on('click', function() {
  get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, openTwitter);
});
```